# C - How to make sure that an array contains 8 integers with the value 0 or 1?

Tags: c, arrays

That's my code so far:

```
int main(void) {
    int byte[8], position = 0, match8 = 0;
    printf("Please enter 1 byte as a binary sequence: ");
    match8 = scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", &byte[0], &byte[1], &byte[2], &byte[3], &byte[4], &byte[5], &byte[6],&byte[7]);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to make sure that the user made a correct input and if not the program should say `"Error! Please enter 1 byte as a binary sequence: "` and check the input again.

I tried:

```
while(getchar() != '\n' || match8 != 8) {
    ...do something
}
```

But I can't figure out how to check if the array contains only 0 and 1.

I hope you can help me with my problem :)

Comment: On most platforms, a `char` has 8 bits. You could use bit shifts and bitwise operations and only one single `char`

Comment: Step 1: `if(match8 != 8) { /* error */ }`, but `scanf` will not check the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
char bits[9], ch;
int byte[8];

while(1){
    printf("Please enter 1 byte as a binary sequence: ");fflush(stdout);
    bits[8] = 1, ch = 0;
    if(2 == scanf(" %8[01]%c", bits, &ch) && ch == '\n' && bits[8] == 0)
        break;
    if(ch != '\n')
        while(getchar() != '\n');//clear input
    printf("Error! ");
}
sscanf(bits, "%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", &byte[0], &byte[1], &byte[2], &byte[3], &byte[4], &byte[5], &byte[6],&byte[7]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A scanset `%8[01]` could be used to restrict input to the characters 0 and 1. The 8 will also limit input to 8 characters. The characters can be converted to numbers with `number = onezero[i] - '0';`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void) {
    char onezero[9] = "";
    int valid = 0;

    do {
        printf("Please enter 1 byte as a binary sequence: ");
        if ( ( 1 == ( valid = scanf ( " %8[01]", onezero))) && ( 8 == strlen ( onezero))) {
            printf ( "input was %s\n", onezero);
        }
        else {
            if ( valid == EOF) {
                break;
            }
            while ( getchar ( ) != '\n') {}
            valid = 0;
        }
    } while ( !valid);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to avoid `scanf()` and use `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
```

Then use `strspn()` to test `buf[]` for only `'0'` or `'1'`

> `size_t strspn(const char *s1, const char *s2);`
>   The `strspn` function computes the length of the maximum initial segment of the string pointed to by `s1` which consists entirely of characters from the string pointed to by `s2`.  C11 7.23.5.6

```
  size_t offset = strspn(buf, "01");
  if (buf[offset] == '\n') {
    buf[offset--] = '\0'; // eat trailing \n
  }
  if (offset == 8 && buf[offset] == '\0') {
    sscanf(buf, "%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d", 
        &byte[0], &byte[1], &byte[2], &byte[3], &byte[4], &byte[5], &byte[6],&byte[7]);
    // Success!
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this...

```
int main(void) {

int byte[8]={0};

    printf("Please enter 1 byte as a binary sequence: ");
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) 
{
byte[i]=getchar()-'0';
if(byte[i]!=0&&byte[i]!=1) /*error*/;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. Even if the input is correct it displays Error

Comment: @VenatorScientiae if you hit "Enter" between each digit, it won't work, because that is not weeded out here.

Comment: i didn't hit enter between each digit.